# How to NSMutableArray section object index value replace?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my array

```
(
        (
        3,
        3,
        3
    ),
        (
        2
    ),
        (
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    )
)
```

I want to replace section object value 
using following code

```
 [[sectionarray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
```

for example

```
[[sectionarray[0] objectAtIndex:1]replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"4"];
```

but app is crashed and the error I get is

```
-[__NSCFConstantString replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a218
```

How to replace array section object value?

Comment: you have 3 arrays right?

Comment: yes this are 3 array

Comment: you have 3 separate arrays and want to replace some objects of some array with some other object from another array right?

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: "A" array added "a","b","c" array  i want replace "A" array inside array "a" replace this array object

Comment: -[__NSCFConstantString replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a218

Comment: Please show us what you want the result to be. I'm still unclear as to what's replacing what.

Comment: this array ( ( 3, 3, 3 ), ( 2 ), ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ) ) i want out put is ( ( 3, 3, 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ) )  i want any section array object index value change

Answer (score 1):

You are calling replaceObjectAtIndex on the object inside the array instead of on the array itself. This should work:

```
[[sectionarray[indexPath.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
```

Comment: `@"0"` should be `@(0)` (those are numbers, not strings).

Comment: @trojanfoe The code in the question shows that OP wants to replace the object with a string. The crash also shows that the objects in the array are strings.

Comment: I think it's up to them though as we don't know what this code is supposed to be doing. It isn't the cause of the crash so I didn't bring it up.

Comment: thanks James  this above code using resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting another level there into objects.

```
( ( 3, 3, 3 ), ( 2 ), ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ) )
```

Lets do your code's anatomy:

```
NSMutableArray *array = sectionarray[indexPath.section]; //gives you an array.
id obj = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] //give you the strings 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1,1
```

and you're calling replace on a string

```
[obj replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
```

**Solution:** You should do following:

```
//First get the array at that section
NSMutableArray *arrayAtSection = sectionarray[indexPath.section];
//Now replace the object
[arrayAtSection replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
```

Writing in your way of coding is:

```
[sectionarray[indexPath.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
```

Comment: thanks for response but i want use sectionarray..                                                this is my orignal  array( ( 3, 3, 3 ), ( 2 ), ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ) ) i want out put like this type array ( ( 3, 3, 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ) )

Comment: @RohitRananaware make sure you added NSMutableArrays in the section array. Now your desired array is at index 1 of section array. Which means, section 1, row 0. And you can replace it with new string or number.